# How to use git on locally cloned repositories to list pull request titles, status, date in bash / shell

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I copied about 10000 repositories to a local drive in order to do some data analysis for a university project.

So far i managed to loop through all folders using a shell script and extract the comments, timestamps and so on as CSV using git log with some modifications.

Now i need to extract all pull request including title, status and date.

I've already tried using the github api, sadly due to the large amount of data i need to extract my github access limit of 5000requests/hour quickly reaches the limit.

Thats why i downloaded all the data to an external drive.

To get the pull request data from the repo folders i've tried to use git combined with log --merges and --first-parent.

Sadly i don't get the expected results.

```
#!/bin/bash

#the first script looks like this. Works fine so far.
#loop through repo folders
cat repolist.txt | while read repolist; do

        #replace all "/" with "_" because of filename issues
        reponame="$(echo "$repolist" | tr '/:?+' '_')";
        #export results to textfiles with the right naming
        git -C test/$repolist log --pretty=format:%ad,%h,%an,%cn,%ae,%s > "exportedfiles/"$reponame".csv";

done

## the second script looks like this so far
git -C folder/repofolder log --first-parent --merges >name.txt
```

the expected result should deliver something like:
pull-request date | pull-request title | pull-request status(merge,close,open)

I'm thankful for any ideas on this problem.

Comment: Pull request title, status, etc., is only available via the GitHub API. If this is a one-time data extraction job and performance doesn't matter much then you could `sleep` the script at points to deliberately rate-limit how many requests you are sending to the GitHub API.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pull requests are not a git concept.  This is part of the "value add" that hosting solutions like github provide.

Since git itself doesn't really understand pull requests, local clones don't necessarily reflect the information you want.  That is, by default they don't have information about pull requests, and depending on how the pull requests are managed by the particular hosting software, it might be possible to fetch some (but not necessarily all) of the information you want, if you know how to interpret it.

github does use refs to represent at least some information about pull requests, but they aren't refs that a normal `clone` bothers to copy.  IF you clone with the `--mirror` option, you will find refs named `refs/pull/<#>/head` and `refs/pull/<#>/merge`.

(You also could use `git fetch` to specifically request these refs for a repo that was cloned the "normal" way.)

But as far as I can tell from eyeballing an example repo, that's all the information you get; these point directly to `COMMIT` objects (like lightweight tags would) so they don't convey any extra metadata.  Presumably the github server has its own record of info about the PR, and that record simply doesn't seem to be available locally